# Como agrupar um array de objetos em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando agrupar um array de objetos. O array deve ser agrupado seguindo essa citação:

> Agrupe pelo `type` respeitando a sequência.

**Array que desejo agrupar**

```
var arrayDeObjetos = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];
```

**A maneira que desejo que seja agrupado:**

```
var newArray = [
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user1"},
      {type: "user", text: "user2"},
      {type: "user", text: "user3"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk1"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user4"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk2"},
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk3"}
  ],  
    
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user5"},
      {type: "user", text: "user6"} 
  ]
];
```

**O que já tentei:**

Estou tentando utilizar um filtro mas sem sucesso já que ele até agrupa todos que sejam do mesmo `type`, porém sem respeitar a sequência que desejo (do array acima):

```
var arrayDeObjetos = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];

var newArray = [];

newArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayDeObjetos, 'clerk'));
newArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayDeObjetos, 'user'));

console.log(newArray);

function filtrarArray(array, type) {
    return array.filter(function (val) {
        return val.type === type;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema com o seu código (além de ser estático para os tipos `user` e `clerk` – o que é problemático em casos nos quais os tipos são dinâmicos em relação ao código fonte) é que, ao invés de percorrer o array um a um, respeitando a *interpolação* de objetos com tipos diferentes, você fez duas varreduras de modo a obter e agrupar os todos os objetos pelo respectivo tipo, mas ignora a separação causada pela interpolação. Ou seja, você simplesmente está desconsiderando o fato de que os grupos devem ser interpolados entre si.

Um exemplo simples para entender o que é interpolação:

```
A A A B B A B A B B
```

Veja que, embora temos 5 `A`s na sequência acima, devido aos `B`s interpolados, ocorrem 3 grupos de `A`, e não um. Analogamente, devido aos `A`s interpolados, temos 3 grupos de `B`.

Desse modo, o que você precisa fazer para resolver esse problema é um pouco mais *complicado* do que você já fez, mas também é bem simples, veja:

A lógica que você quer é um pouco mais complexa do que você já tem, mas uma ideia simples (e relativamente eficiente, já que se percorre o array somente uma vez) e pensar em *grupos*:

- Basicamente um grupo é composto por objetos *seguidos* que têm o mesmo tipo entre si.
- Você começa com um grupo, inicialmente definido com o primeiro objeto do array recebido.
- Iterando pelos próximos elementos, você:

  - Insere o objeto correspondente à iteração atual se for do mesmo tipo do anteiror;
  - Cria um novo grupo se o objeto da iteração atual for de tipo diferente. Nesse caso, você deve inserir o grupo anterior no array resultante.

Veja que em código também continua relativamente simples:

```js
// Função auxiliar para retornar o último elemento do array.
function last(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

function groupInterpolated(arr) {
  const result = [];

  // Já iniciamos com o primeiro elemento do grupo preenchido.
  let currGroup = [arr[0]];

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const currObj = arr[i];

    // Grupos diferentes, então precisamos criar um novo grupo antes de inserir
    // o objeto atual no array correspondente ao grupo.
    if (currObj.type !== last(currGroup).type) {
      result.push(currGroup);
      currGroup = []; // <-- Novo grupo!
    }

    // Neste ponto temos certeza que estamos mexendo no grupo adequado, então
    // podemos inserir o objeto da iteração atual nele.
    currGroup.push(currObj);
  }

  // Inserir o último grupo no resultado.
  result.push(currGroup);

  return result;
}

const arr = [
  { type: 'user', text: 'user1' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user2' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user3' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk1' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user4' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk2' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk3' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user5' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user6' }
];

console.log(groupInterpolated(arr));
```

Claro que o que temos aqui é apenas uma sugestão (bem simplista, se me permite dizer). Tem como encurtar bastante o código (além de, claro, implementá-lo de outras maneiras), mas preferi não o fazer para fins de legibilidade.

Comment: Veja se esse [código](https://ideone.com/1mrYyI) pode ser aproveitado em sua resposta.

Comment: Poderia sim, @AugustoVasques, é uma outra forma de implementar. Achei que ficou bem legal, inclusive. Obrigado por isso. ^^